# Android random user interface behavior

Tags: android, user-interface

Okay I have a full week of frustration behind me, it is the third time that the layout behaves random.

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGebiedHead"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Geef gebied op"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvGebieden"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

</ListView>
```

produces a result where the listview is displayed on top of the textview (making both items unreadable). The code down here produces the desired result, the listview is rendered under the textview. It is not the eclipse graphical editor, but it happens on a real phone as well. Note that the only difference between the two snippets is the id of the TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Geef gebied op"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvGebieden"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

</ListView>
```

Earlier this week I had a fight with the layout of four togglebuttons which (all!!) changed size, text align on the button, and even location when I clicked one, while the on and off text was exactly the same. Please tell me I am doing something wrong and android is not broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example on the top, your ListView's `layout_below` still refers to `@id/textView1` which doesn't exist. It does, however, in your example at the bottom, so the bottom is working. FYI, instead of `@+id/textView1` you should use `@id\textView1` in the `layout_below`.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I got crazy.